# How to restore mouse pointer in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, mouse, gnome

Sometimes the image of the mouse pointer will get corrupted. I can still use the mouse but because the image is corrupted it is somewhat difficult. How can I get the mouse pointer back without logging out?

Edit: I noticed that the mouse corruption goes away when VMPlayer is shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **System/Preferences/Appearance**,and choose **Theme** tab,then click **Customize...** and choose **pointer** tab,here you can choose the mouse pointer type(or image as you said?).