# Ubuntu mouse cursor broken

Tags: ubuntu, mouse-cursor

In certain applications in Ubuntu, my mouse cursor becomes a square (more or less transparent with some pixels being black)! Why is it only happening in some applications (i.e. Kile and Inkspace)?

Does anyone know what the problem is, and if there is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To change the mouse cursor theme system-wide (including for Java applications), you need to do these steps:

Download the custom theme and extract it into /usr/share/icons/

Example:

```
wget -O /tmp/ComixCursors-0.7.3.tar.bz2 http://www.limitland.de/comixcursors/ComixCursors-0.7.3.tar.bz2
tar -C /usr/share/icons/ -xjvf /tmp/ComixCursors-0.7.3.tar.bz2
```

change the cursor theme to the downloaded theme via the GUI (Appearances > Pointer) or via Gnome/Ubuntu Tweak tool. But that's only half the solution.

Next, open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

select the number corresponding to your choice
log out of desktop (or restart)
log back in

Answer (score 0):

Select a different custom cursor/theme in Appearance:

[How to restore mouse pointer in Gnome](https://superuser.com/questions/175559/how-to-restore-mouse-pointer-in-gnome)